# CoreData: error: Serious application error. Exception was caught during Core Data change processing

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsnotificationcenter

I am running into major issues developing my iphone app.

here is the full error:

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data 
change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of 
NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[TimeSpentStudying coordinate]:
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x21db92d0 with userInfo (null)
```

This is weird because I have two coreData entities ( Locations &  TimeSpentStudying). But I dont think those are the problems. `[TimeSpentStudying coordinate]` is weird, because I do not have a `coordinate` property sent on `TimeSpentStudying` core data class

I have a mapView set up, and when a user taps on the detail disclosure button on an mkannotationview, a new view (LibraryTrackTimeViewController) pops up, but is pretty much unusable. I tried calling NSLog in viewDidLoad and nothing showed up.

mapViewController.m

```
#pragma mark - NSNotification

- (void)contextDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  if ([self isViewLoaded]) {
    [self updateLocations];
}
```

.

```
- (void)updateLocations
{
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Location" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSError *error;
NSArray * foundObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (foundObjects == nil) {
    FATAL_CORE_DATA_ERROR(error);
    return;
    }

    if (locations != nil) {
    [self.mapView removeAnnotations:locations];
    }

locations = foundObjects;
[self.mapView addAnnotations:locations];
```

}

```
-(void)dealloc
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
    name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification
    object:self.managedObjectContext];
}
```

the error I think might have to do with the prepareForSegue method in mapViewController.m

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  if (distance < 500) {
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"TrackLibraryTimes"]) {
    UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;

LibraryTrackTimeViewController *controller = (LibraryTrackTimeViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
  }
 }}
```

I apologize for the rough syntax, I am just getting used to SO, if you need any more code, please let me know, thanks all.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Also, great question!

Comment: The error message clearly states that the `coordinate` message is sent to an instance of `TimeSpentStudying`, probably the object with address 0x21db92d0. So at some point you are working with a `TimeSpentStudying` object where a different type (`Locations`?) is expected. Due to the dynamic method resolution in Objective-C, such problems are often revealed only at runtime. You should try to locate the problem, e.g. by setting a breakpoint on all Objective-C exceptions.

Answer (score 8):

I had same error, due to

```
-(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath

case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            //[self.tableView insert
            NSLog(@"change insert");
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
```

I had used `indexPath` instead of newIndexPath.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed the issue by deallocating the fetched results controller. It was still performing fetches as I was adding/editing objects in a separate screen.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the complexity of your project, a quick way to catch this is to implement the offending method and set a breakpoint there. When you hit the breakpoint, you can see where it was called, and Bob's your uncle.

So you could put something like

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate{
    // set a breakpoint on the next line
    NSParameterAssert(false);
    return nil;
}
```

in your `TimeSpentStudying` class and see where it gets called.

Just make sure you delete it when you're done.

Answer (score -3):

COuple of things I would try.

1. Delete the application from simulator and clean the app and run again.
2. Looking at your code, I feel you are passing around the managedContextObject from one controller to another, no need to do that. User AppDelegate sharedInstance to get managedObject whenever you want. It's not going to create multiple instances, it's a singleton object.

Try these two and hopefully, you might find some answer or may be fix it.

Comment: Voted down b/c you actually never want to do that with Core Data, and always pass around the MOC using the "pass the baton" approach that Apple recommends.